# Specific and general possibility in the future

Tags: modal-verbs, future-constructions

I study English grammar using a grammar book. There is a unit about modal verbs. The unit includes seven topics. Three of them are the most difficult for me. They are about ability, possibility and speculation. I've read them and for each grammar rule provided some examples just to practice them. Now I'm trying not just to give some examples but also to see how these grammar rules are different from each other.

I'm learning the possibility topic now. It has three sections. For the present, the past and the future.

**For the past** there is a rule which says "We use 'could' to talk about general possibility in the past".
My simple examples:

- Health insurance could be very expensive
- Health insurance could be expensive
- Health insurance could be cheap

And another rule which says "We use 'might' or 'could' + have + past participle to talk about a specific possibility in the past".
My simple examples:

- He might have been playing a video game at that time
- He might have been in a grocery store at that time
- He might have been having dinner at that time

**For the present** there is a grammar rule which says "We use 'can' to talk about things which are generally possible in the present".
My simple examples:

- Health insurance can be very expensive
- Health insurance can be expensive
- Health insurance can be cheap

There is also another rule which says "We usually use 'may', 'might' and 'could' to talk about specific possibilities in the present".
My simple examples:

- He might be playing a video game
- He might be in a grocery store
- He might be having dinner

Before I start talking about the future which I actually have a problem with I want to say I understand these rules like possibilities not like speculation especially talking about specific possibility for both the present and past which might be considered like speculation. So from my perspective I can say "He might be playing a video game" talking about one action or option which is possible for him at this moment of time so "He might be playing a video game" or "He might be having dinner". But I can also guess saying "He might be playing a video game" and in this situation I'm saying what I think he is actually doing but I'm not very certain about it. The same for specific possibility in the past. So here in my question I'm asking about possibility but I've written how I understand the difference between specific possibility and speculation to see the way of my thinking.

**For the future** there is a rule which says "we use 'will/won't be able to' to talk about future possibility or impossibility".

- First of all, it's not clear whether it relates to general possibility or specific possibility in the future
- and for me using 'will be able to' sounds weird for possibility in the future, it's more about ability/capability in the future. So I don't understand why the authors put this rule in the topic about future possibility.

The authors' example for the rule:
"We'll be able to get a coffee at the theater but we won't be able to eat until after the show".

And there is another rule which says "We use 'may', 'might' or 'could' to talk about future actions which are less certain".

- For me the rule is not related to future possibility as well, it's more about guessing or speculating about the future.
- And it's also not clear whether it's related to specific possibility or general possibility in the future.

The authors' example for the rule: "The directors may call a stockholders' meeting".

**Conclusion**

I like how the authors provides grammar rules for the present and past but for the future it's not clear and confusing. There is also nothing how to say that something is impossible or how to make negative sentences both for specific and general possibility and also for the present, past and future.

I hope someone who knows exactly how to talk about possibility will help me.

Comment: Let me correct your usage of the present simple right away. You say "I study English grammar using a grammar book" etc. but I believe you mean: I'm studying English grammar using a grammar book. It's important to get the simple present right.

Comment: I'm not sure your "Past, Present, Future" categories are very helpful here. Your very first example *NOUN could be ADJECTIVE* occurs more often as a "conditional" assertion relating to a *specific* instance of NOUN, for which the exact applicability of ADJECTIVE hasn't yet been determined. For example, *Your hospital treatment **could be** expensive* (but we don't yet know the cost). As opposed to the "generic" assertion *Hospital treatment **can be** expensive*. What governs the ***could / can*** choice there isn't "time" - it's "specificity".

Comment: (What Lambie says is nit-picking style advice. There's nothing wrong with your first sentence.)

Comment: "Health insurance could be cheap" is not at all necessarily past. could can be two things: the past of can and a possibility. We could leave now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I study English using a grammar book [everday, every week, etc]. I truly doubt that was the meaning here.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Lambie: Perhaps *you* should study English using a grammar book everday, if you're trying to imply that OP's Simple Present somehow implies "continuously" in a way that ***I'm studying English grammar*** doesn't. They're just stylistic choices.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree. I thinking the  continuous is better here. He does on to describe a whole process.

Comment: I'm not arguing about which is "better". I'm saying it's a stylistic choice. It's unreasonable to give the OP here the impression there's anything actually syntactically or semantically incorrect about his choice.

Comment: To get back to the question - I don't see any distinction between 'possibility' and 'speculation'.  What they call speculation is just 'making a guess' as to where a person might be (or whatever it is).

Comment: Артем Малышев - Realistically, I think your question is "Too Broad" to survive and be adequately answered here. Your *"We'll be able to get a coffee at the theater but we won't be able to eat until after the show"* is just one possible phrasing for the context. Native speakers are as likely to say *"...but we **can't** eat until after the show"* regardless of whether they started with ***won't be able*** or ***can't***. You shouldn't assume that just because a textbook presents an example, that's the only valid way to phrase it.

Comment: One wonders who wrote the stupid textbook.

Comment: For the past, a rule says "We use 'could' to talk about general possibility in the past". Yes, it could be that was true. But 'could' does not define the past at all. The rest of the sentence has to do that: "Health insurance could be expensive [in the 60's]."

Comment: Forgive me, but this question is very long and I'm not sure what kind of answer is needed. Can you edit to ask **one**, clear question which can get a clear answer?

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for your comment but I feel I should use the present simple rather than the present continuous in the sentence "I study English grammar using a grammar book" because I literally do it every day and it's a permanent activity for me:) But I respect your choice and I think I can use the present continuous instead as well.

Comment: I'm gonna ask another question to simplify this one. Thank you all for your support!