# Are these grammar rules from a grammar book good to learn how to talk about possibility?

Tags: modal-verbs

I study English grammar. I use a grammar book for it. Now I'm learning modal verbs and the possibility topic is difficult and confusing for me.

Here is the screenshot from the textbook:
[image]

I'm not asking whether it's enough to talk about possibility in English. I think no. I'm asking about the way the authors decided to organize the learning process about possibility. For me the present and past possibility sections are clear to understand but the future section is not.

I asked a more detailed question before. Here is a link: [Specific and general possibility in the future](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346248/specific-and-general-possibility-in-the-future)
There you can find the way of my understanding about this topic. But here I can just want to see whether it's good or not to follow these rules from the textbook just to start talking about possibility in English.

Comment: What the textbook says is accurate. (You haven't told us what book it is!)

Comment: @KateBunting The book is MyGrammarLab Advanced C1–C2.

Comment: Artem, I will help you fix a very common error made by learners. You are studying English and using a grammar book to do so. We would not say here: I study and I use. Before you try to master all those forms, I suggest you find and do some grammar exercises for the simple present and present progressive. Also, these pages of text are for a more advanced student. I suggest you look for something simpler and only use those pages you posted for reference, but not for learning various modal forms.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Language Learning site.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for your comment. Can you suggest something for learners, any books or some specific websites?

Comment: Try this site: https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-could-have-should-have-would-have/3391128.html

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. I've used it before. But for me as an engineer it seemed less organised in contrast to a textbook. Difficult for my mindset :(

Comment: Then, try one of these: https://www.cambridgebookshop.co.uk/collections/elt

Comment: @Lambie I've heard about these textbooks but never used. Ok, I'll give it a try:) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments by Kate Bunting: *What the textbook says is accurate*.

> But here I…just want to see whether it's good or not to follow
> these rules from the textbook just to start talking about possibility
> in English.

Since the title of the book is: **MyGrammarLab Advanced C1–C2**, one can deduce that the authors are presenting their material with the assumption that students have a mastery of Beginning/Intermediate concepts. Moreover, the use of such a label as *Academic English* should imply that students can expect to do a certain amount of nit-picking (in both the students’ most proficient language and the examples presented in the text) to understand the material comprehensively.